# How can 突き抜けた be interpreted in this sentence?

Tags: translation, word-choice, verbs

I was reading an interview for a video game (if it helps, the genre is action) and the producer says this:

> シナリオをつなげていくと、どうしても突き抜けたプレイ感覚が減ってしまうんですよ。 これが痛い。

What is he trying to say by 突き抜けた?
I understand what the verb means but I can't find a way to describe it in English...Also, I found on a website with synonyms that 突き抜けた means 中途半端ではない様子 and it listed 半端ない as a synonym but I don't believe that's related, but it's what I found when I was looking into other meanings. I thought that it could have been an expression used in the context of video games...

Comment: 突き抜けた modifies プレイ感覚, not プレイ.

Comment: @l'électeur Ah you're right! Still, how can it be translated?

Comment: I'll leave it to the experts here, but I hope you at least know that 突き抜けた only has very positive meanings.  Your comment "I don't believe that's related." makes one wonder if you actually know that.

Comment: @l'électeur
I didn't know that it can have only positive meaning because I mainly have seen the verb 突き抜ける used in context with the meanings of "to break/come/pierce through", hence why I couldn't figure out what the producer is implying...Then, like I mentioned, I found the verb written in the past tense here https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E7%AA%81%E3%81%8D%E6%8A%9C%E3%81%91%E3%81%9F and it didn't have those meanings...
If I were to translate directly, wouldn't it be "a piercing sense of gameplay"? which sounds odd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context it refers to a play feeling much better than one can usually expect, so 中途半端ではない is not far. The underlying image is that something has gone through an imaginary barrier and may have gone far, not restricted by anything. Possible translation in this context would be *outstanding*, *incomparable*, *mind-blowing*, *overwhelming*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what the producer was trying to say.

When you break or pierce through something, you are not being stopped by that thing as you move forward. I guess such a sense of “through-ness” is considered important for a video game, and the producer is suggesting that they could not achieve that if they worried too much about the integrity of the storyline, or something like that.